# Mandarin equivalent of the English opening word 'since'?

Tags: grammar

In English, we often use the word since in the context such as

'Since it's hot outside, we should stay inside' and introduce a cause and effect. I know there's the phrase 因为。。所以 and I could also say

外面太热， 我们应该不出门。

But I want to know if there's a word that gives something like 'since' in English.

Comment: A more native expression should be “我们**不应该**出门”。 Also you don't need the extra space after punctuation in Chinese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you would like to know the word **既然** for since.

*ABC English*'s entry for since says:

> 2 因为 yīnwèi; 既然 jìrán
>
> Since you're so smart, you do it.
> 既然你这么聪明,你来做吧。
> Jìrán nǐ zhème cōngming, nǐ lái zuò ba.

---

But, I think you've already grasped something more fundamentally important from the example sentence you wrote: you don't translate since into colloquial Chinese. You can just as simply put two sentences together and the context will be clear, while words like 既然 are seldom heard in spoken Chinese.

Comment: Thank you. If I want to say 'You act as if you are so smart. You do it', then how do I express the 'as if' part? 你表演你这么聪明， 你来做吧？

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of "since" and "because" is that "since" suggests a much weaker logical relationships. So in Chinese, the conjunction is often omitted.

One characteristic of Chinese is that we use a lot of short sentence connected by commas as apposed to many individual sentence ended with a period. So somehow the comma acts as a logical connection between the two shorter sentence.

So

> 外面太热，我们不应该出门。

suggests a much stronger logical relationship than

> 外面太热。我们不应该出门。

If you really want one word this kind of relationship, you can use 那么 as "thus"

> 外面太热，**那**/**那么**我们不应该出门。